# GameObject does not rotate using TwoHandManipulatable nor BoundingBoxRig using Unity and HoloLens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a GameObject in a Unity project for HoloLens with HoloToolKit, which I need to rotate. The object has a BoxCollider and HandDraggable script, and I'm also adding a TapToPlace component in runtime. The scripts that I've tried for rotation are TwoHandManipulatable and BoundingBoxRig, and they work to resize the object, but no matter what I do, the object does not rotate.

This is how I tried with BoundingBoxRig:

[image]

And this is how it looks with TwoHandManipulatable:

[image]

None of these works, only for resize. I would appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me all I had to to to get it to work was to add the `Transform` of your `arrow2` to the box of the `Two Hand Manipulatable`. Just click and hold on `Transform` and drag it into the box next to `Host Transform`. I added it to my project and it looks like this:

[image: Two hand in my project]

Also I don't think you need the `Hand Draggable` Script if you have the `Two Hand Manipulatable` because the last checkbox in the `Two Hand Manupulatable` enables movement with one hand if you want it.

Edit: I have an `Animator` on it but you don't need that. I have it because I made the model in Blender and it got added automatically.